# Wrong Dates in R and D3

Tags: r, d3.js, google-analytics, nvd3.js

I'm analyzing Google Analytics data in R and presenting it with NVD3 through the rCharts package. However, I think dates are being set in the wrong time zone at some point in the process, as every data point in the chart is one day early (June 21 v. the correct June 22.) **N.B.** Google Analytics is set to report in EST, at least in the web app.

```
sources <- ga$getData(...) # Using rga to pull data from Analytics

> dput(sources)
structure(list(date = structure(c(16243, 16243, 16243, 16243, 
16244, 16244, 16244), class = "Date"), medium = c("(none)", "cpc", 
"organic", "referral", "(none)", "cpc", "organic"), sessions = c(9, 
50, 5, 3, 3, 68, 9)), .Names = c("date", "medium", "sessions"
), row.names = c(NA, 7L), class = "data.frame")

lineChart <- nPlot(sessions ~ date, group = 'medium', data = sources, type = "lineWithFocusChart")
lineChart$xAxis(tickFormat = "#!function(d) {return d3.time.format('%b %d')(new Date(d*1000*3600*24)); }!#") # Fixing date to show only month and day (ordinal) 
lineChart$show()
```

Comment: R Dates do not have timezones (and when coerced to datetimes in R, midnight in GMT is used). Does D3 have a date-class that you should be using?

Comment: It seems so, but unfortunately it's flying way over my head. https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack but then so was the original call (I think you are 4 hours behind CST/GMT, but it's possible that you need to change the 4 to a five. I needed to change it to a 7 since I'm on the Left Coast.)

```
lineChart$xAxis(tickFormat = "#!function(d) {return d3.time.format(
                       '%b %d')(new Date(d*1000*3600*24+4*60*60*1000)); }!#") 
lineChart$show()
```

Comment: Yep, seems to be working. Doesn't matter that it's hacky, as this is just for display Thanks for the assist..